# How can i set html multiple attribute to razor dropdown?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have this html code :

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
                                                <option>Mustard</option>
                                                <option>Ketchup</option>
                                                <option>Relish</option>
                                            </select>
```

the multiple key very important to me and try to use in this razor syntax:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LinksSelected, new SelectList(ViewBag.Tickets[0].Links, "linkID", "linkName")
                                           , new { @class = "selectpicker" , @multiple } )
```

How can i solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use multiple = "multiple" to replace `@multiple`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LinksSelected, new SelectList(ViewBag.Tickets[0].Links, "linkID", "linkName")
                                           , new { @class = "selectpicker" , multiple = "multiple" } )
```